# UIWebView Showing the XML Response as Plan Text

Tags: ios, uiwebview

This might be a difficult problem to explain. I have a UIWebView which makes a web service request and gets XML back.

```
<ArrayOfSomething xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://Mobileapps.com/">
<tokenMappings>
<UpdateStatus>0</UpdateStatus>
<TokenNo>0</TokenNo>
</tokenMappings>
</ArrayOfSomething>
```

When it receives the above XML it displays "0 0" in the browser. Is there anyway to prevent it from displaying the response? I must make the above request but I only need to extract the UpdateStatus and TokenNo without displaying the response.

- This is a Hybrid App running inside the UIWebView *

Comment: If you don't need to display the response why don't you use a http request (not ui) instead of a UIWebView, which is a UI element ?

Comment: This is a hybrid app which is running inside the UIWebView.

Comment: So make the request with javascript and process the result

Comment: Is there no way to do this on UIWebView native side?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you want your app, that is running in an uiwebview, start a native url request? is that correct ?

This works but you should consider about using requests in javascript.

Try this:

I guess you already implemented the UIWebViewDelegate protocol and assigned the delegate to your current view controller.

Now implement

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"yourPrefix:"]) {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourserver/xml"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setValue:@"YOUR NEEDED CONTENT TYPE" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {   
         NSLog(@"response : %@", response.description);
         NSLog(@"response : %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Now in your javascript code where you want to start the request you do this:

```
window.location.href = "yourPrefix://";
```

This starts a redirect to the URL and the native method is called an starts your request.

Comment: Thanks! But I still need to make that request and extract data from the response but not display the output of the response in UIWebView. Currently, when the response comes I extract it and then load a different web page inside the UIWebView. But for 1-2 seconds you can see the response displayed in the UIWebView which I do not want.